# Tkinter. I need to replace a photo in the same column when I click a button

Tags: button, grid, tkinter

Take a look at this code please.

```
#normal template stuff
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
win=Tk()
win.geometry('+0+0')
win.title(" Borderlands 2 Chicks")
#How to add intro photo
img = Image.open("intro.gif")
intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
right = Label(win, image=intro)
right.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5)


#defernitions to call photos
def but1():
img = Image.open("captain_scarlett.gif")
intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
right1 = Label(win, image=intro)
right1.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5,)    

def but2():
img = Image.open("Ellie.gif")
intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
right = Label(win, image=intro)
right.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5)

def but3():
img = Image.open("Gaige Swin Suit.gif")
intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
right = Label(win, image=intro)
right.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5)

def but4():
img = Image.open("Gaige.gif")
intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
right = Label(win, image=intro)
right.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5)


#buttons on the left column
left1 = Button(win, text=" Captian Scarlet")
left1.configure(command=but1)
left2 = Button(win, text=" Button 2 ")
left2.configure(command=but2)
left3 = Button(win, text=" Button 3 ")
left3.configure(command=but3)
left4 = Button(win, text=" Button 4 ")
left4.configure(command=but4)
left1.grid(row=0, column=0)
left2.grid(row=2, column=0)
left3.grid(row=3, column=0)
left4.grid(row=4, column=0)

#how to get buttons to do something
def but1(): print "Button one was pushed"

mainloop()
```

This app displays good at first. I press the first button and the right column goes compleaty white. What I need is code that replaces what ever photo is currenty in the right column after I press any button. I been studying `Destroy()` and `grid_forget()` but I can't find example code that works on this App. Please help.

Comment: Your indentation is all wrong. If you want us to take time to answer your question, please take time to format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating images in a function and storing a reference to those images in a local variable. When the function is finished, the local variable goes out of scope and the image object is garbage-collected. You need to keep a persistent reference to the image.

The other problem in your code is that each time you push the button you create a new image and new label. Over time this will use up a lot of memory unnecessarily.  You don't need to keep creating new buttons and images. You can change the label of an image after you create it.

For example, you could create a simple list of images, and then reconfigure the label when you press the button. Here's an example of how I would do it:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class View(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._initialize_images()
        self.right1 = tk.Label(self, image=self.images[0])
        self.right1.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5)

        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 1", command=self.set_image_1)
        b2 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 2", command=self.set_image_2)
        b3 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 3", command=self.set_image_3)
        b4 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 4", command=self.set_image_4)

        b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        b2.grid(row=2, column=0)
        b3.grid(row=4, column=0)
        b4.grid(row=6, column=0)

    # these can all be consolidated into a single function with the number
    # passed in as a parameter. I chose not to do that since that might
    # add confusion for someone just learning how to write Tkinter code
    def set_image_1(self):
        self.right1.configure(image=self.images[1])
    def set_image_2(self):
        self.right1.configure(image=self.images[2])
    def set_image_3(self):
        self.right1.configure(image=self.images[3])
    def set_image_4(self):
        self.right1.configure(image=self.images[4])

    def _initialize_images(self):
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(tk.PhotoImage(file="intro.gif"))
        self.images.append(tk.PhotoImage(file="captain_scarlett.gif"))
        self.images.append(tk.PhotoImage(file="Ellie.gif"))
        self.images.append(tk.PhotoImage(file="Gaige Swin Suit.gif"))
        self.images.append(tk.PhotoImage(file="Gaige.gif"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    view = View(root)
    view.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

N.B. I chose to use an object-oriented style because it makes creating GUIs considerably easier. Using a class to define your main window gives you a handy place to keep persistent references to other objects without cluttering up the global namespace.